# QVector (3D) [] operator not consistent in 3 level for-loop

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QVector<QVector<QVector<double> > > qvec_3d;` which I am trying to assign values to in a 3-layer for loop, e.g. `qvec_3d[i][j][k] = some_double;`, but while debugging in QCreator 4.12.1, qvec_3d is just full of zeros after this assignment. However, if I explicitly write `qvec_3d[0][0][0] = 30000;` the debugger shows 30000 just fine. I've already `resized(to_some_size)` each vector and filed with zeros. What am I doing wrong? Am using Qt 5.7.0. Do I need an older version of Qt Creator? (Need to use Qt 5.7.0).

Comment: There's too little code to tell. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I suspect you pass the vector to a function by value. Just guessing because, as said, there is no code to see what's going on.